# Do we need implement defer = "defer" to all scripts except internal scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading the "Professional Javascript for web developers" and I find it says

> The purpose of `defer` is to indicate that a script won't be changing the structure of the page as it executes. As such, the script can be run safely after the entire page has been parsed.

Hence, the `defer` is good for our program, I want to know if we need to put the defer in all scripts except internal scripts?

Comment: You can only defer external scripts, you can't defer internal scripts. You only put defer on scripts you want to execute after the page has rendered. this allows you to remove the `DOMContentLoaded` event in those scripts (there is more to it than just that though). So putting it on all scripts is a case-by-case basis.